# Code optimization for my vector to columns

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

Would there be a better way to better optimize this code in R

```
df = data.frame("Population" = c("4.88M", "3.12M", "819k",  "4660",  "46.7k", "4.86M", "856k"))
int_list <- numeric(nrow(df))
for (y in 1:nrow(df)) {
  i <- df$Population[y]
  if (str_detect(i, "k")){
    no_k <- gsub("k", "", i)
    x <- as.numeric(no_k)
    fix_X <- x * 1000
  } else if (str_detect(i, "M")) {
    no_M <- gsub("M", "", i)
    x <- as.numeric(no_M)
    fix_X <- x * 1000000
  } else {
    fix_X <- as.numeric(i)
  }
  int_list[y] = fix_X
}
df$pop_fix <- int_list
```

EDIT: added an example DF

I got the result I needed just wondering if I could do better
I have tried ifelse statements but they always lead to errors and I've also tried to just put it in the column but then it overwrites the past values to the last one

Comment: Certainly it can. We just don't know how your DataFrame looks like, so it's hard to help you much at all

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Here is a one-liner. No packages are used.

```
transform(df, pop_fix = as.numeric(sub("k", "e3", sub("M", "e6", Population))))
##   Population pop_fix
## 1      4.88M 4880000
## 2      3.12M 3120000
## 3       819k  819000
## 4       4660    4660
## 5      46.7k   46700
## 6      4.86M 4860000
## 7       856k  856000
```

**2)** or using `Reduce`

```
L <- list(k = "e3", M = "e6")
transform(df, pop_fix = as.numeric(Reduce(\(x, nm) sub(nm, L[[nm]], x), 
  init = Population, names(L))))
```

**3)** This also works and conceptually does both substitutions at once:

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(df, pop_fix = as.numeric(gsubfn(".", list(M="e6",k="e3"), Population)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at simplifying. Strip out everything but the `k/M` suffixes, then strip out the `k/M`, and use some indexing of the suffixes to determine the multiplier:

```
sel <- gsub("[^Mk]", "", df$Population)
val <- as.numeric(gsub("[Mk]",  "", df$Population))
df$pop_fix2 <- ifelse(sel == "", val, val * c("M"=1000000, "k"=1000)[sel])
```

Gives the requested result:

```
#  Population pop_fix pop_fix2
#1      4.88M 4880000  4880000
#2      3.12M 3120000  3120000
#3       819k  819000   819000
#4       4660    4660     4660
#5      46.7k   46700    46700
#6      4.86M 4860000  4860000
#7       856k  856000   856000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the tidyverse. First `separate` the numeric from the exponentiator. Then convert the symbolic exponentiator to a proper base 10 number, and finally adjust the population by a simple multiplication.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
    separate_wider_regex(col = Population,
                         patterns = c(population = "[0-9.]+",
                                      magnitude = "[A-Za-z]"),
                         too_few = "align_start"
    ) |> type_convert() |>
    mutate(magnitude = case_match(magnitude,
                                  "M" ~ 6,
                                  "k" ~ 3,
                                  .default = 1
                                  )
           ) |> 
    mutate(population = population * (10^ magnitude),
           .keep = "none")

# A tibble: 7 × 1
  population
       <dbl>
1    4880000
2    3120000
3     819000
4      46600
5      46700
6    4860000
7     856000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[c("pop", "pop_scale")] <- data.table::tstrsplit(df$Population, "(?=(M|k))", perl = TRUE)
df$pop_scale              <- replace(df$pop_scale, is.na(df$pop_scale), "as_is")
df$pop                    <- as.numeric(df$pop)
df$pop_fix                <- df$pop * c(M=1e6, k=1e3, as_is=1)[df$pop_scale]


#   Population     pop pop_scale pop_fix
# 1      4.88M    4.88         M 4880000
# 2      3.12M    3.12         M 3120000
# 3       819k  819.00         k  819000
# 4       4660 4660.00     as_is    4660
# 5      46.7k   46.70         k   46700
# 6      4.86M    4.86         M 4860000
# 7       856k  856.00         k  856000
```